# If I reincarnate a character into a different class do I keep all of the Unique abilities for the original class?

Tags: disgaea-5

For example, I finally have a level 150 Sage so I have Land Decimator. If I reincarnate into a Catsaber will I have a Level 1 Catsaber that knows Land Decimator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the unique skills do not carry over.  It's used to learn the extra skills, like all the fire/wind/ice/star spells, buffs, healing, etc.  So when you reincarnate back into a Sage, you will have access to Multi-Attacker and Land Decimator.